# Proof of $f(x+c) \rightarrow m$ as $x \rightarrow a$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x) \rightarrow m$ as $x \rightarrow a+c$ then $f(x+c) \rightarrow m$ as $x \rightarrow a$.

Proof: Because of the assumption, we have $\forall \varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ s.t. $|f(x)-m|<\varepsilon$ whenever $0<|x-(a+c)|<\delta$.

We are trying to get to (correct if I am wrong): $|f(x+c)-m|< \varepsilon$, whenever $0<|(x+c)-a|< \delta$.

$|x-(a+c)|=|((x+c)-a)-2c|$ so $|(x+c)-a|-2|c| \leq|((x+c)-a)-2c| <\delta$ so $|(x+c)-a|<\delta +2|c|$ which is a problem since that isn't smaller than $\delta$.

Help.

Comment: Correction: You are trying to get "... whenever $0 < \lvert x-a\rvert < \delta$".

Comment: Oh thanks. I would still have the same situation though...

Comment: No, you would have $\lvert (x+c) - (a+c)\rvert =\dotsc$

Comment: I would have $|x-(a+c)| \geq |x-a|-|c| > \delta$ so $|x-a| \leq \delta +|c|$.

Comment: Perhaps the use of the same letter in both situations confuses you. You have $\lim\limits_{y\to a+c} f(y) = m$. You want $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x+c) = m$.